# Automate pixel fallback using REM units throughout a project

Tags: css, sass, pixel, mixing

I checked the following [article](http://zerosixthree.se/8-sass-mixins-you-must-have-in-your-toolbox/) in which it presented the following mixing:

**rem font size with pixel fallback**

```
@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return $remSize * 1rem;
}

@mixin font-size($size) {
  font-size: $size;
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}
```

I feel very confortable using rem on my projects, after placing `font-size: 62.5%` on the html so `1rem = 10pixels`.

But I would like to know if there is a mixing or a method to create a pixel fallback for any rem used in a whole project, as for example:

```
&:before{
    color: white;
    margin: 0 0.5rem 0 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    width: 3.2rem;
}
```

In this case the margin-right = 5pixels and width 32pixels. The issue with rem units is that IE8, Opera mini or Safari 3.2 is not supported. So the site would not be correctly visible from any of these browsers.

Is there a way to automate the pixel fallback using rem throughout a project?

Comment: have you seen this one (based in less but may be useful) http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/less-mixin-for-rem-font-sizing/

Comment: @James Donnelly It seems the answer of Karl Merkli on this page is the answer I look for.

Comment: @James Donnelly A good reason to use REM is that is has the benefits of using EM right? As for example if they wish to zoom or make the typography bigger. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution so you can use the rem to px mixin for any property:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 10px;
  @return #{$remSize}rem;
}

@mixin rem($propertie, $value) {
  #{$propertie}: $value;
  #{$propertie}: calculateRem($value);
}

p {
  font-size: calculateRem(32px);
  @include rem(width, 100px);
  @include rem(margin, 50px);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

p {
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  width: 100px; /* Fallback */
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 50px; /* FallBack */
  margin: 5rem;
}
```

An example: http://sassmeister.com/gist/e888e641925002b5895c

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work with shortcut properties that contain mixed values.

```
// Global Var
$root-font-size: 16;

@mixin rem($property, $values) {
  $pxvalues: null;
  $remvalues: null;

  @each $value in $values{
    $pxvalue: null;
    $remvalue: null;
    @if type-of($value) == 'number'{
      @if ($value > 0 or $value < 0){
        $pxvalue: ($value)+px;
        $remvalue: ($value / $root-font-size)+rem;
      } @else {
        $pxvalue: $value;
        $remvalue: $value;
      }
    } @else {
      $pxvalue: $value;
      $remvalue: $value;
    }

    $pxvalues: append($pxvalues, $pxvalue);
    $remvalues: append($remvalues, $remvalue);

  }

  #{$property}: $pxvalues;
  #{$property}: $remvalues;
}

// Usage: pass pixel values without units
.foo{
  @include rem(margin, 80 auto);
}
```

Output:

```
.foo{
  margin: 80px auto;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
```